# MySQL Truncating of result when using Group_Concat and Concat

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL (I have removed some of the selesct fi:

```
SELECT node_revisions.title                          AS 'Task', 
       node_revisions.body                           AS 'Description', 
       Date_format(field_due_date_value, '%e/%c/%Y') AS 'Due Date', 
       users.name                                    AS 'User Name', 
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Concat(CHAR(10),Concat_ws( ' - ', name, From_unixtime( TIMESTAMP, 
               '%e/%c/%Y' )),CHAR(10),COMMENT))
        FROM   comments 
        WHERE  comments.nid = content_type_task.nid) AS 'Comments' 
FROM   content_type_task 
       INNER JOIN users 
         ON content_type_task.field_assigned_to_uid = users.uid 
       INNER JOIN node_revisions 
         ON content_type_task.vid = node_revisions.vid 
ORDER  BY content_type_task.nid DESC
```

This pulls back all my tasks and all comments associated with a task. The problem I am having is that the comments field; created using the *GROUP_CONCAT*, is truncating the output. I don't know why and I don't know how to overcome this. (It looks to be at 341ish chars)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GROUP_CONCAT() is, by default, limited to 1024 bytes.

To work around this limitation and allow up to 100 KBytes of data,
add `group_concat_max_len=102400` in my.cnf
or query the server using `SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len=102400`.

Comment: Strangely executing the SET GLOBAL in the command line client didn't work but the .my.cnf setting did the trick. (v.5.0.37)

Answer (score 10):

As Andre mentioned, the result of `GROUP_CONCAT()` is limited to `group_concat_max_len` bytes.

However, when using `GROUP_CONCAT` with `ORDER BY`, the result is further truncated to **one third** of `group_concat_max_len`.  This is why your original result was being truncated to 341 (= 1024/3) bytes.  If you remove the `ORDER BY` clause, this should return up to the full 1024 bytes for `Comments`.  For example:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    `Id` INTEGER,
    `Type` VARCHAR(10),
    `Data` TEXT
);

INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES
(0, 'Alpha', 'ABCDEF'),
(1, 'Alpha', 'GHIJKL'),
(2, 'Alpha', 'MNOPQR'),
(3, 'Alpha', 'STUVWX'),
(4, 'Alpha', 'YZ'),
(5, 'Numeric', '12345'),
(6, 'Numeric', '67890');

SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 26;

-- Returns 26 bytes of data
SELECT Type, GROUP_CONCAT(Data SEPARATOR '') AS AllData_Unordered
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Type;

-- Returns 26/3 = 8 bytes of data
SELECT Type, GROUP_CONCAT(Data SEPARATOR '') AS AllData_Ordered
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Type
ORDER BY Id;

DROP TABLE MyTable;
```

Will return

```
Type    AllData_Unordered
Alpha   ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
Numeric 1234567890

Type    AllData_Ordered
Alpha   ABCDEFGH
Numeric 12345678
```

I have not found this interaction between `GROUP_CONCAT()` and `ORDER BY` mentioned in the [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), but it affects at least MySQL Server 5.1.

Comment: I think the interaction exists with `UNION` instead of `ORDER BY` as well.