# MySQL truncates concatenated result of a GROUP_CONCAT function

Tags: mysql, view, types, truncate

I've created a view which uses `GROUP_CONCAT` to concatenate results from a query on products column with data type of `'varchar(7) utf8_general_ci'` in a column named `concat_products`.

The problem is that MySQL truncates value of "concat_products" column.
phpMyAdmin says the data type of "concat_products" column is `varchar(341) utf8_bin`

Table products:

```
CREATE TABLE `products`(
    `productId` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `product` varchar(7) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL, 
    `price` mediumint(5) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`productId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
```

The "concat_products_vw" view:

```
CREATE VIEW concat_products_vw AS
SELECT
  `userId`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('_', `product`, `productId`, `price`) 
        ORDER BY `productId` ASC SEPARATOR '*') AS concat_products
FROM
  `users`
LEFT JOIN `products` 
ON `users`.`accountBalance` >= `product`.`price`
GROUP BY `productId`
```

According to MySQL manual:

> Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings
> Length can be specified as a value from 1 to 255 before MySQL 4.0.2 and 0 to 255 as of MySQL 4.0.2.

---

#### EDIT

`Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 65,535.`

1. Why MySQL specifies more than 255 characters for `varchar` "concat_products" column? (solved!)
2. Why `uf8_bin` instead of `utf8_general_ci`?
3. Is it possible to change the data type of a column in a *view* for example in my case to text for "concat_products" column?
4. If not what can I do to prevent MySQL from truncating "concat_products" column?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Double-check your sources. The [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/char.html) says: Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 65,535.

Comment: @Jocelyn you're right so why truncating takes place here if mysql can store up to 65535 characters in a varchar column?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

As I already wrote in an earlier comment, the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/char.html) says:

> Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can
>   be specified as a value from 0 to 65,535.

So the problem is not with the data type of the field.

The [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) also says:

> The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the
>   group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of
>   1024. The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of
>   max_allowed_packet. The syntax to change the value of
>   group_concat_max_len at runtime is as follows, where val is an
>   unsigned integer:
>   SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = val;

Your options for changing the value of group_concat_max_len are:

1. changing the value at MySQL startup by appending this to the command:
   `--group_concat_max_len=your_value_here`
2. adding this line in your MySQL configuration file (mysql.ini): `group_concat_max_len=your_value_here`
3. running this command after MySQL startup:
   `SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len=your_value_here;`
4. running this command after opening a MySQL connection:
   `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=your_value_here;`

Documentation: [SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-statement.html), [Server System Variables: group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len)

Comment: thanks mysql doesn't truncate the concat_products column anymore

Comment: I personally use the 4th option I listed, because there are only a few of my scripts that need to compute "big" GROUP_CONCAT, and these scripts don't run very often.

Answer (score 14):

As Jocelyn mentioned, the size of a `GROUP_CONCAT()` result is bounded by `group_concat_max_len`, however there is an additional interaction with `ORDER BY` that results in a further truncation to 1/3 of `group_concat_max_len`. For an example, see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37979180/3516590).

The default value for `group_concat_max_len` is 1024, and 1024 / 3 = 341 probably explains why the type of concat_products shows up as `varchar(341)` in the original example.  If you were to remove the `GROUP BY productId` clause, concat_products should show up as `varchar(1024)`.

I have not found this interaction between `GROUP_CONCAT()` and `ORDER BY` mentioned in the [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), but it affects at least MySQL Server 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Year 2023, on Linux Server you can edit `my.cnf` file and then set:

```bash
[mysqld]
group_concat_max_len = 2048
```